# Enforce HTTPS in IIS without using cache unsafe server variables

Tags: iis, https, url-rewriting, iis-10

I'm currently using the following rule to enforce https on a site:

```
<rule name="Enforce HTTPS" enabled="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" ignoreCase="true" pattern="^off$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

The problem is that the HTTPS server variable that I'm using in the condition is not part of the list of server variables that "do not cause any effect on output caching policy" ([see full list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference)).

The reason why this is a problem is that after setting up some Failed Request Tracing Rules, I realized that some entries have the following warning : **REWRITE_DISABLED_KERNEL_CACHE**

[image]

After some research, I found a related [forum thread](https://forums.iis.net/t/1228668.aspx) mentioning that:

> The URL Rewrite Module will disable kernel mode cache if any rule in a
> rule set had a condition that used cache unsafe server variable. The
> cache was disabled regardless whether the requested URL matched the
> rule pattern or not.

This wouldn't be a problem if performance wasn't an issue, but the site isn't that fast and I'm wondering if this cache problem couldn't be part of the issue.

From reading the list of safe variables, it seems like there is none that will contain the protocol used for the request, so this doesn't seem possible, but I still thought I might ask just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue and solved this by routing the HTTP traffic into a separate IIS application that contains nothing more than a single web.config file that routes the traffic into the HTTPS application. So the web.config file in the HTTPS application is free of any unsafe variables.

Answer (score 1):

We can bypass the HTTP protocol to access the website using HTTPS, and then use the IIS log to view the visit records of the website, where each record contains the time consumption of the visit.

```
Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs- 
version cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken  

2020-04-15 02:50:57 fe80::a4fe:6d79:f2b8:d031%6 GET / - 446 - 
fe80::a4fe:6d79:f2b8:d031%6 HTTP/2 Mozilla/5.0+ 
(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+ 
(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/80.0.3987.163+Safari/537.36
- 403 14 0 2158
```

The last field indicates the time-taken in one request.
I don’t think IIS output cache will have a significant impact on IIS website access performance when only checking the HTTPS server variable and redirect the URI.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the input and I do agree that the impact is probably not significant, but I'm  going to wait to see if there is actually an answer to the original question that avoid having the mentioned warning message.